# Transfer to remote host using ssh (jenkins)

Tags: jenkins, ssh

I have a compressed file in my jenkins workspace folder, I am trying to transfer that compressed file over ssh, but I got `SSH: Transferred 0 file(s)`

My Configurations are below-

- Transfer set source file: my-files.zip
- Remove Prefix:
- Remote directory: /home/my-files

My Console Output:

```
Started by user Mizanur Rahman
SSH: Transferred 0 file(s)
Build step 'Send files or execute commands over SSH' changed build result to SUCCESS
Finished: SUCCESS
```

Answer (score 0):

The first test would be to try and replicate that tranfer manually, from the server executing the job, with the user running the job.

On that server, try at least a:

```
ssh -Tv xxx@remote.com
```

That will confirm if you (as the user running the Jenkins job) actually establish an secure shell session. Replace `xxx` and `remote.com` by the remote user and remote server target for that session.